# Ordering Softlayer Netscaler VPX via API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I ordered a Netscaler vpx using the following code,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @netscalar-vpx-data.json https://<userid>:<apikey>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrdernter code here
```

and the json payload in netscalar-vpx-data is

```
{
"parameters": [
    {
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller",
        "quantity": 1,
        "location": "DALLAS09",
        "packageId": 192,
        "prices": [
            {
                "id": 44964
            },
            {
                "id": 17238
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

The Order was successful. However later we got contacted by Softlayer support. They mentioned that they need to cancel that order, as the private VLAn does not exist for the account behind that POD and It will need to be re ordered behind a POD that already has vlans.

We had Network vlans in our environment. And we were successfully able to create a Netscaler VPX by ordering via the control.softlayer.com portal.

Can you tell us the correct way to order Netscaler via API.?
Additionally how can we verify that we have the required private vlans.

Thank You.

Comment: Update: we ordered Citrix NetScaler VPX 10.5 10Mbps Standard

Answer (score 1):

Your Request is fine, using your request by defatul the newly created NetScaler will take any of your created VLANs in the "DALLAS09" datacenter, so you need to make sure that you have VLANS on that datacenter. Also you can try setting the VLANS see the code below.

```
{
    "parameters": [{
        "hardware": [{
            "primaryBackendNetworkComponent": {
                "networkVlanId": 1084325
            },
            "primaryNetworkComponent": {
                "networkVlanId": 361652
            }
        }],
        "location": "DALLAS09",
        "packageId": 192,
        "quantity": 1,
        "prices": [{
            "id": 44964
        }, {
            "id": 17238

        }]
    }]
}
```

Regards

Comment: I tried putting the additional parameters
"primaryBackendNetworkComponent": {
                "networkVlanId": 1084325
            },
            "primaryNetworkComponent": {
                "networkVlanId": 361652
            }

but it didnt help. The Netscaler record gets created, but is not configured. It does not have management ip or any other information associated with it

Comment: It is strange that is the way that the portal orders the netscalers in my account it works fine, I think better you ask to the softlayer employee what it is valid datacenters which contains your VLANs.